# Do not break content inside div

Tags: html, css, printing, mpdf, export-to-pdf

How do I tell mpdf to move div content to next page instead of breaking it in the middle? I found some mpdf-specific tags but it did not help me. Any ideas?

```
<div> <!-- content inside div should not be broken -->
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <ul>
        <li n:foreach="$teacherSummary as $teacher => $children">
            {$teacher}: {array_unique($children)|implode:', '}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p><strong>{$event->note}</strong></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is CSS property [`page-break-inside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside) that works in mpdf as well.

**Usage**:

```
<div style="page-break-inside:avoid !important;">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <ul>
        <li n:foreach="$teacherSummary as $teacher => $children">
            {$teacher}: {array_unique($children)|implode:', '}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p><strong>{$event->note}</strong></p>
</div>
```